# const char* as argument for constexpr constructor

Tags: c++, string, templates, compile-time

I am trying to make a custom string class that involves a constexpr constructor that allows counted initialization at compile time. Unfortunately, the problem of not being able to overload a constexpr constructor/function with a non-constexpr function/constructor seems to be getting in the way.

This isn't a problem if the struct is meant to stay as that literal its entire lifetime, or if the struct is never meant to be constructed with a non literal value. But the goal of this struct is if it is made using a literal or any kind of constexpr value, it is counted at compile time and initialized as a const string. But, if it is initialized using some non constexpr value, or it is changed after being initialized with a constexpr value, it allocates itself and stops acting like a literal.

This problem can be solved using 2 different structs, but I would like to try not doing that, for the fun of it. But C++ really doesn't seem to want me to.

Here is the string struct as of now:

```
typedef unsigned int u32;

struct string{
    u32 count;
    u32 space;
    
    char* str;
    const char* literal;
    
    string(){
        count = 0;
        space = 0;
        str   = 0;
    }
    
    template<u32 N> constexpr inline 
    string(const char (&s)[N]) : 
    literal(s), 
    str((char*)s),
    count(N-1), 
    space(0) {}
    
    string(const char* s){
        count  = strlen(s);
        space = RoundUpTo(count+1, 4);
        str = (char*)calloc(space, sizeof(char));
        memcpy(str, s, count* sizeof(char));
    }
};
```

when the overloaded non-constexpr constructor is included it always prefers to use it regardless of if its given a literal or not, except when given a `const char[N]`.

My next attempt was to just remove the overloaded function, but the issue this now causes is I can't use a variable of type `const char*` to initialize a string, only `const char[N]`. This makes sense I guess, but I'm hoping there's someway around this.

In essence, all I want is to be able to put a char literal into a string struct, without counting its characters at runtime.

Comment: Shouldn't you be allocating `N+1` characters for your string in your templated code? What will happen with your `string.str` when your input array goes out of scope? Basically, what you do in your non templated constructor.

Comment: @rturrado I might be misunderstanding what you mean, but the templated code shouldn't be allocating anything, the count is set as N-1 because it doesn't include the terminating character of a string.

Comment: I was referring to two facts: if you get an array of `N` chars 1) you may want to copy those `N` chars to your `str` and add a null character in the end; that's why I mentioned you may want to allocate `N+1` characters for your string. 2) you should copy that array to your `str`; otherwise, if your `string` outlives the array, `str` will contain a dangling reference. The following code tries to demonstrate those two points: https://godbolt.org/z/PWfexjn17